# HorizontalListView Selector

Tags: android

i have a HorizontalListView https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView with several items inside, each of these items has a relative layout enclosing some text and an image. i have added a selector to this relative layouts and it works great in newer versions of android setting white the relativelayout of each item white when is pressed.

the problem is that in older versions of android the HorizontalListview starts acting weird when i scroll, this is because  i add  android:clickable="true" to each relative layout. if i remove this attribute the HLV starts working normally but the selector wont work.

Here is my Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/marcoNota"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tile_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
        android:background="@drawable/tile_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

I even tried setting an onTouchListener on the adapter obtaining the same result.

I would like to know if its possible to use a selector whitout setting Clickable="true" or any work around on this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to use an onItemClickListener, [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), but I don't know if it would give any different result than onTouchListener

Comment: no it gives the same result, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem implementing the following methods in HorizontalListView.java:

this was used to detect Action_UP (when the user lifts the finger off the selected view and paint the relative layout holding it back to default color):

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(habilitar){
            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                    View child = getChildAt(i);
                    if (isEventWithinView2(event, child)) {
                        if(mOnItemUnSelectedListener != null){
                            mOnItemUnSelectedListener.onItemUnSelected(child);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if(mOnItemUnSelectedListener != null && child != null){
                        mOnItemUnSelectedListener.onItemUnSelected(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Inside mOnGesture gesturedetector declaration i added this functionality to onDown method. this allowed to paint the selected item relative layout holding the contents when the user pressed on the view:

```
for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
                    View child = getChildAt(i);
                    if (isEventWithinView2(e, child)) {
                        if(mOnItemSelected != null){
                            mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

then i added some listeners to allow the adapter paint the pressed view, for the unselection listener i implemented the following interface:

```
private OnItemUnSelectedListener mOnItemUnSelectedListener;

public void setOnItemUnSelectedListener(OnItemUnSelectedListener listener ){
        mOnItemUnSelectedListener = listener;

}
public interface OnItemUnSelectedListener{
    public void onItemUnSelected(View v);
}
```

for the item selected listener i used the one already defined in the class:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
```

finally in my adapter i set the listeners:

```
HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) retval.findViewById(R.id.listviewH);
listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
listview.setOnItemUnSelectedListener(this);
```

and i set the color of the layout depending if the user is pressing or not the view

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
        if(arg1.findViewById(R.id.marcoNota) != null){
            arg1.findViewById(R.id.marcoNota).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemUnSelected(View v) {
        if(v.findViewById(R.id.marcoNota) != null){
        v.findViewById(R.id.marcoNota).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

i know it is a very specific question but here it is if anyone needs to do the same.